# Inline Folium Map Displaying only one point

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, folium

I am attempting to map a bunch of points from a .csv file within Jupyter Notebook using [folium](http://folium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html). Within my dataframe I have two columns named "Latitude" and "Longitude" which hold coordinate information as floats.

Here is the code I am using: **EDIT TO INCLUDE DATAFRAME CODE

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import FastMarkerCluster
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import re
import os
import branca.colormap as cm
import re
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('D:/documents/professional/school/hunter/data/Retail_Food_Stores.csv')
print(folium.__version__)
```

Import .csv and modules

```
def createLatLong(location):
try:
    return re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', location)
except:
    return None

def createLatLongColsX(item):
    for items in df_nyc['Lat_Long']:
        for item in items:
            try:
                return re.split(',', item)[0]
            except:
                return None

def createLatLongColsY(item):
    for items in df_nyc['Lat_Long']:
        for item in items:
            try:
                return re.split(',', item)[1]
            except:
                return None

df_nyc['Latitude'] = df_nyc['Location'].apply(createLatLongColsX)
df_nyc['Longitude'] = df_nyc['Location'].apply(createLatLongColsY)
df_nyc['Latitude'] = df_nyc['Latitude'].astype(float).fillna(0.0)
df_nyc['Longitude'] = df_nyc['Longitude'].astype(float).fillna(0.0)
```

Create columns holding point values

```
this_map = folium.Map(prefer_canvas=True)

def plotDot(point):
try:
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[point.Latitude, point.Longitude],
                        radius=2,
                        weight=10,#remove outline
                        popup = point['Entity Name'],
                        fill_color='#000000').add_to(this_map)
except:
    break

df.apply(plotDot, axis = 1, raw=True)

this_map.fit_bounds(this_map.get_bounds())

this_map
```

Create map and apply to dataframe rows

Fortunately, the map does display somewhat correctly in that it is appearing within the notebook. However, the point which appears is always the same regardless of how I slice the dataframe. Interestingly the name displayed in the popup when the point is clicked is always the last item name in the sliced portion of my dataframe.

So, it seems like it's pulling in the name correctly, but not populating the marker locations correctly. Using Python 2.7 within the notebook.

EDIT 2 -
    Est_Type_Long   Latitude  Longitude
    0    [Multiple Operations, Store, Food Manufacturer]  40.676932 -73.969136
    1    [Multiple Operations, Store, Food Manufacturer]  40.676932 -73.969136
    2    [Multiple Operations, Store, Food Manufacturer]  40.676932 -73.969136
    3  [Multiple Operations, Store, Bakery, Food Manu...  40.676932 -73.969136
    4    [Multiple Operations, Store, Food Manufacturer]  40.676932 -73.969136

Comment: I would omit `raw=True` in your apply.  When raw is True you're passing numpy arrays to plotDot and you're trying to index them like a Pandas Series

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I omitted the parameter but seem to still be having the issue

Comment: hmmm.  That was the only glaring thing.  Using an apply here is not common, but I don't see anything wrong with that approach off hand.  Can you post some of your dataframe?

Comment: Gladly. Here is a [link](https://imgur.com/a/RaNU0) to images of the dataframe and my full folium code. I  also am attempting to achieve the same goal using a MarkerCluster, but can't seem to get it imported correctly into the notebook from plugins

Comment: I meant as text in your question.  Something we can copy and paste

Comment: We're getting closer :-) .  What I'm really looking for is the output of `print(df_nyc.head())` after you've created your Lat Long columns

Comment: Edit 2 @ bottom of original post. Will delete my edit comments after reply

Comment: Do all your locations have the same Lat Long?

Comment: Thank you. I was overlooking the fact that the way I was pulling the Lat and Longs was incorrect, yielding only one point as you noticed. Fixing that problem cleared up my issue with the folium map and I now have a functioning inline map in my notebook. Thank you so much! Should I delete this question?

Comment: Ok, cool . Yes, I would delete it